# Javascript - Filtering out all map elements if a map with the same type already exists in a list

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

I have a value events of a type `Map<number, List<Event>>`, I am flattening this value like this:

```
const flatEvents = events.valueSeq().flatMap(event => event.values()).toList()
```

The value `flatEvents` looks like this after flattening:

```
[
    {
        "eventTime": "2022-03-18T08:04:00Z",
        "type": "deviated",
        "id": 841,
        "createdAt": "2022-03-18T08:04:43.975332Z",
        "createdBy": "47"
    },
    {
        "eventTime": "2022-03-15T11:11:38.220966Z",
        "type": "created",
        "id": 826,
        "createdAt": "2022-03-15T11:11:38.220966Z",
        "createdBy": "47"
    },
    {
        "eventTime": "2022-03-15T11:11:38.220966Z",
        "id": 827,
        "type": "created",
        "createdAt": "2022-03-15T11:11:38.220966Z",
        "createdBy": "47"
    },
    {
        "eventTime": "2022-03-15T11:11:38.220966Z",
        "type": "created",
        "id": 828,
        "createdAt": "2022-03-15T11:11:38.220966Z",
        "createdBy": "47"
    }
]
```

But, I would also like to filter out all the extra elements that have `type = created`, so that I end up with a list that has only one element where `type == created`:

```
[
    {
        "eventTime": "2022-03-18T08:04:00Z",
        "type": "deviated",
        "id": 841,
        "createdAt": "2022-03-18T08:04:43.975332Z",
        "createdBy": "47"
    },
    {
        "eventTime": "2022-03-15T11:11:38.220966Z",
        "type": "created",
        "id": 826,
        "createdAt": "2022-03-15T11:11:38.220966Z",
        "createdBy": "47"
    }
]
```

I have tried to do it like this:

```
const flatEvents = events.valueSeq()
    .flatMap(event => event.values()).toList()
    .filter((v, _, list) =>
      list.find(v => v.get('type') === 'created'))
```

But, that is returning the same list as before.
I have also tried this:

```
const flatEvents = events.valueSeq()
    .flatMap(event => event.values()).toList()
    .filter((_,i,flattenedEvents) =>
      flattenedEvents.findIndex(consignmentEvent => (consignmentEvent.get('type') === 'created')) === i
    )
```

That filters out extra elements with the `type === 'created'`, but also other elements, so I end up with only this:

```
[
    {
        "eventTime": "2022-03-18T08:04:00Z",
        "type": "deviated",
        "id": 841,
        "createdAt": "2022-03-18T08:04:43.975332Z",
        "createdBy": "47"
    },
 ]
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: this helps ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/56757215/13583510

Comment: something like `flatEvents.filter((v,i,a)=>a.findIndex(v2=>(v2.type===v.type))===i)`

Comment: Is it only for `type == created` or any duplicate type?

Comment: Only for ```type == created```

Comment: @Ludwig try putting a condition like `.filter((v,i,a)=>v.type !== 'created' || a.findIndex(v2=>(v2.type==='created'))===i)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `filter` and include a local counter variable that starts with 0, but is incremented when a "created" type is encountered. This can be used for the actual filtering:

```js
let flatEvents = [{"eventTime": "2022-03-18T08:04:00Z","type": "deviated","id": 841,"createdAt": "2022-03-18T08:04:43.975332Z","createdBy": "47"},{"eventTime": "2022-03-15T11:11:38.220966Z","type": "created","id": 826,"createdAt": "2022-03-15T11:11:38.220966Z","createdBy": "47"},{"eventTime": "2022-03-15T11:11:38.220966Z","id": 827,"type": "created","createdAt": "2022-03-15T11:11:38.220966Z","createdBy": "47"},{"eventTime": "2022-03-15T11:11:38.220966Z","type": "created","id": 828,"createdAt": "2022-03-15T11:11:38.220966Z","createdBy": "47"}];

flatEvents = flatEvents.filter(
   (count => 
        event => event.type != "created" || !count++
   )(0)
); 

console.log(flatEvents);
```

You would chain this `filter()` call after your `toList()` call.

Comment: Didn't know this was possible :) So that's an IIF ? Could you explain a bit the condition?

Comment: Yes, that outer function is invoked immediately (and only once), returning the actual callback function for `filter`. The outer function creates a closure for `count`.

Comment: I did the same logic but with reduce in my answer. But this is neat. Although I'm still struggling to wrap my head about the conditional bit

Comment: `!count` evaluates to true if and only when `count` is still zero. Note that `++` makes the increment *after* the evaluation of `count`.

Comment: Yup, it's all in that order of things :) Thanks. I learned something neat

Answer (score 0):

Removing duplicates only concerns events with `type = 'created'`, therefore, the following:

```
const result = flatEvents.reduce((prev, curr) => {
    return prev.find(e => e.type === "created") ?
        prev :
        [...prev, curr]
}, []
)
```

We are reducing the array to another array (i.e. filtering but with access to `prev` which in this case are the events iterated over so far). For each `curr` event we check if there is already an event with `type=== "created"` in `prev` and return accordingly.

---

Or if you want it attached to your previous operations:

```
const flatEvents = events
    .valueSeq()
    .flatMap(event => event.values())
    .toList()
    .reduce((prev, curr) =>
        prev.find(e => e.type === "created") ?
            prev :
            [...prev, curr]
        , []
    )
```

---

**Output**
Only one (first) event with `type = "created"` is kept. However duplicates are allowed for other types:

```
[
  {
    eventTime: '2022-03-18T08:04:00Z',
    type: 'deviated',
    id: 841,
    createdAt: '2022-03-18T08:04:43.975332Z',
    createdBy: '47'
  },
  {
    eventTime: '2022-03-15T11:11:38.220966Z',
    type: 'created',
    id: 826,
    createdAt: '2022-03-15T11:11:38.220966Z',
    createdBy: '47'
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

For O(n) plus readability you can always go safe and use a for loop:

```
const filterEvents = (events) => {
    let result = [];
    let foundCreatedType = false;
    for (let event of events) {
        if (event.type === "created" && !foundCreatedType) {
            result.push(event)
            foundCreatedType = true;
        } else {
            if (event.type !== "created") result.push(event)
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

So after you used your toList() just apply filterEvents on the result